# Remove all non-numeric characters from a CString

Tags: clarion

I need to format a CString that contains a phone number.

I need to remove all spaces and all characters that are not a number.

Please advice on how I can do this.

```
tel1 = replace(tel1,' ','')
```

That is how it would be done in C# but I don't have a clue how to do it in Clarion.

Answer (score 2):

As Griffo mentioned, the built-in procedure DeFormat should do this for you.

There is no online help for Clarion, this is copied from relevant section:

> The DEFORMAT procedure removes formatting characters from a numeric string, returning only the numbers contained in the string.

```
tel1 = '(02) 1234-5678'
tel1 = DeFormat(tel1)
! tel1 now contains 0212345678
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tel1 = deformat(tel1)
```

Check out Deformat in your help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster - this was actually the right answer, though a little lacking in details. Griffo - next time add an example, and for a language like Clarion that doesn't have online docs, copy the info from your docs up here for everyone to reference.